# AARCH64 gcc #include <stdint.h> fails

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, arm64, stdint

I am trying to compile some kernel code for a raspberry pi 3 from a x86 computer using the aarch64 cross compiler in one of my source files I require stdint.h however when I try to compile it fails saying

```
>make
rm kernel8.elf *.o >/dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
rm -rf *.o *.img *.elf
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wall -c start.s -o start.o
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wall -c delays.c -o delays.o
In file included from gpio.h:4:0,
                 from delays.c:26:
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/stdint.h:9:16: fatal error: stdint.h:     No such file or directory
 # include_next <stdint.h>
                ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:15: delays.o] Error 1
```

I am running Fedors 26 and have used

```
sudo dnf install *aarch64*
```

so I have all the appropriate packages or should have.

Comment: You need to check few things: 1) `uname -a` (make sure the kernel is arm8) 2) are you build tools installed (run following command: `sudo apt-get install -y bc build-essential gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu`).

Comment: Compile with `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors` to ensure that you are using gcc in C compiler mode.

Comment: @MilindDeore My question was unclear I have now clarrified that I am using the aarch64 compiler as a cross compiler from a x86 based computer.

Comment: @Lundin I have edited my makefile to incorporate what you suggested it made no difference.

Comment: @OliverStrong Does installing the package `glibc-headers` fix it?

Comment: @Candy No it does not as I already have it installed.

Comment: @OliverStrong I am having the same problem, have you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the latest [Linaro toolchain](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/aarch64-linux-gnu/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-i686_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz) for x86: I have had a couple of issues in the past with ARM cross-compilers provided with mainstream Debian/Ubuntu.

Using the following stdint.c example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("The size of an uint32_t is %d.\n", sizeof(uint32_t));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
mkdir -p /opt/linaro
wget https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/aarch64-linux-gnu/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-i686_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz
tar Jxvf gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-i686_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz -C /opt/linaro
/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-i686_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -o stdint stdint.c
```

The compilation should succeed, and you should get a working AARCH64 executable:

```
readelf -h stdint
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           AArch64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x4003f0
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          4872008 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         6
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         37
  Section header string table index: 36
```

If you have an x86_64 development PC, using the [x86_64 version](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/aarch64-linux-gnu/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz) of the Linaro toolchain would of course be preferable.